# My ultegra front 3x derailleur adjustment screws are seized and the shift is unreliable into the small cog. Can I replace it with something similar?

Tags: derailleur, compatibility, front

I need to replace my 15-year old Ultegra triple front derailleur. I can't find the same model for sale online. What alternative options can I try please?

Comment: What model do you have?  Without that, any answer listing possible replacements would only be a guess.  Although a 105 triple derailleur contemporary with your Ultegra derailleur would probably be a pretty good guess.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know the model - it's not specified in the original shop receipt. Will I find it on the cage perhaps?

Comment: The conversation is more about the cranks and what rings are on them that what exactly the old FD was. The model number is on the frame side of the cage. Fifteen years ago implies FD-6603.